# Which type of creatures could exist in a volcano world?

Tags: creature-design, volcanoes

Yes, no one, only bacteria and with luck.

Let's suppose that:

- It is a fantasy world;
- The creatures live in a dormant volcanoes zone;
- The neighbors volcanoes are about 5 km and they are still active;
- Their power supply is the heat.

**How could be their anatomy?**

Comment: You've stated it's a fantasy world. Do you want magical creatures? Or biologically sound ones? Or a mix of both?

Comment: A mix of both would be interesting :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

In fact they already do, even without a fantasy element. There are any number of [extremophiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremophile) that live in high temperature environments (which volcanoes tend to be). There are also extremophiles that live in highly acidic or basic environments. Then we've got some of the more exotic bacteria and plants that live in the dark and feed off volcanic vent activity at the bottom of the sea.

Now: Most of these tend to be simple lifeforms, and they all like having water around (though some of them don't seem to care if it's so acidic it can eat metal). Either your volcanoes get regularly rained on and the environment is very humid, you're next to the sea, or the volcanoes interact with a subterranean aquifer of some kind. Slimes and gels are the order of the day. Oh yeah..

Since you're in a fantasy environment we can expand the criteria a bit. Sentient, acidic slimes can be quite the hazard. Nests of burrowing worms that eat silicates aren't out of the question (and are horrible if they fall on your head). Plantlife (of a sort. Probably best not to try eat them) can exist, using heat to bind resources leached from the rocks using acid distilled from the vapours in the air. If you want to you can build a whole ecosystem based around hot, acidic creatures. They will suffer from hypothermia if you move them far from their natural habitat though, and though they might be able to eat us I doubt we'd have the right PH to make a tasty snack.

Unless you're willing to dive very deep into the realm of fantasy you can't have things living in the lava. While you might conceivably be able to handwave heat resistance into them, anything that sinks in lava is going to have to be denser than the molten rock it's living in, which means either your lava-dwellers actually float on the surface or they take years to sink/emerge, and they've got to be ungodly strong. While lava looks like it flows easily, it actually doesn't. It's still as dense as granite and has a tendency to freeze around cooler things that get put into it.

Bring on the Flaming Jesus Lizards.

Answer (score 1):

Well, they could be just about anything, but make it heat resistant. Dragons with fireproof scales that can support molten stone, lava crabs, NO PLANTS, pretty much anything. Probably some kind of fireproof reptile, fish, or amphibian that can stand the weight of molten rock. And won't burn.

These creatures would probably die in cooler temperatures, though. I mean, they're used to living around molten rock and fire. Ice probably doesn't agree with them.

Answer (score 1):

The lowest level of the food chain would probably some type of fungi or or maybe even some plants that manage to grow in the less volcanic parts of the planet ( perhaps above some sort of underground stream) like some kind of Oasis or something. Even the Sahara  there are places where plants grow. If this planet didn't have any then maybe some type of fungi good makeup the lower level of the food chain smaller animals would eat the fungi and they would be eaten by bigger animals who in turn to be eaten by bigger animals. The creatures on this planet are most likely be cold blooded. After all there's no need hold heat inside of your body if the entire planet is boiling. Depending on the amount  of lava you might see lizards with wings or maybe some sort of special fireproof feet that allowed them to walk a short distance across lava.